# Laravel: How can I bootstrap my modules in the Kernel scheduler

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel app, I want to schedule some tasks using the [scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling). In order not to duplicate code, I want to re-use functionality already in some of my Modules. I specifically made one `CronModule`, that uses some of the other modules for it's job.
In my `app/Console/Kernel.php` I have this for the schedule function:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $cronmodule = $this->app->make('App\Dashboard\Modules\CronModule');
    $schedule->call(function () {
        echo "======yes";

    })->everyMinute();
}
```

The problem that I run into, is that some of my other modules make use of the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` Facade, which is aliased in config\app.php to "Auth". I don't actually need the Auth facade to work for any of the functions called by my CronModule. Of course that wouldn't make sense in the scope of CronJobs. But I think the modules for some reason can't find that Facade already when importing it, and so running `php artisan schedule:run` errors out with

> [ErrorException]
>     Use of undefined constant Auth - assumed 'Auth' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: That's weird, all aliases should work fine in jobs. Could you show the code for `CronModule`? Or at least the part where you use `Auth`.

Comment: You are totally right. The alias was there. We made a small mistake in one of the other modules that caused it. I spent much too much time on a wild goose chase :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @DolfAndringa You should share what the solution was, in case others end up in a similar situation. :)

Comment: @AkenRoberts as I commented above, the solution was that there was a different error in my code somewhere that caused this. So it is not related to the original question.